# CocosBuilder Animation Editor: Prevent animation from resetting the scene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

In CocosBuilder, one can set animation of an object (e.g. CCSprite, CCNode) using animation editor (timeline).

However, if I play an animation, say, moving object A for 200 px and play another animation, say, moving object B for 300 px, CocosBuilder always reset the position of the first object (A) back to the original place before playing second animation.

That is, I cannot retain effect of any animation once another animation is played.
My work-around is to create a copy of object A an set it to be visible at the new position, an set the original A to invisible. But this is very clumsy and impractical.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try to chain the animations together?  It's in one of the tutorials floating around the 'net.  There was one by Zynga that had some pretty good info.

Comment: No, chaining does not help here. The two animations do not have anything to do with each other. They are merely effects of events. For example, when the user tap on object A, it moves. And when user taps on B, it moves. But the two animations are not chained together.

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 separate ccb files (one for each object) and drag and drop them onto your main scene. Each ccb will have the relevant animations e.g., the ccb for object A will have the animation that translates it 200 px. In this way the animations are independent.